# How can I use a specific FormControl from a FromArray in my HTML Document?

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript

I'm initializing my `FormArray` with this code

```
this.contents.forEach(content=> {
       this.formArray.push( new FormControl(content.text, Validators.required));
    });
```

and I want to link one `FormControl` with my `textarea` and change it with my ID.

```
<textarea matInput id="content-textarea" placeholder="Required" [formControlName]="formArray.at(id)"></textarea>
```

But I get this error message:

> **ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute**

How can i use a specific `FormControl` from a `FormArray` in my HTML Document?

***EDIT***: I cant use a FormControl if i dont have one. I got this error message because my Content-Array was empty and i tried to use the FormControl.
So i have a different problem. But thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you directly use `formcontrol` instead of `formcontrolname`

```
 <textarea matInput id="content-textarea" placeholder="Required" [formControl]="formArray.controls[0]"></textarea>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-angular-3asxne)

Comment: I get the same Errormessage. The problem is i cant use just formcontrolname="formArray.controls[0]".

Comment: did you change it to ` [formControl]="formArray.controls[0]"`

Comment: Yes and also [formControl]="formArray.at[0]". I tried both

Comment: The Problem was somewhere else... you can check my Edit if you are interested. Thank you :)

Comment: use a *ngIf to avoid errors when you has no array `<input *ngIf="formArray" [formControl]="formArray.at[0]">` or `<input *ngIf="formArray && formArray.length>0" [formControl]="formArray.at[0]">` if you create at first the formArray with an empty array

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this, can't show demo it's part of the big module:

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of docInfoForm.controls.Documents.controls; let i = index;" [formGroup]="file" class="form-group">
    <td>
      <fa class="cust-file-icon" [name]="file.get('Name').value | fileTypeIcon"></fa>
      <input [attr.id]="'file-type-' + i" type="hidden" class="form-control" formControlName="Type" placeholder="File Size">
    </td>
    <td class="left">
      <text-control [ctr-id]="'file-name-' + i" [label-text]="'File Name'" formControlName="Name"
        [error-text]="'File Name is required'" [mandatory]="true" [form-ctr]="file.controls.Name">
      </text-control>
    </td>
    <td class="left">
      <text-control [ctr-id]="'file-desc-' + i" [label-text]="'Description'" formControlName="Description"></text-control>
    </td>
    <td class="left">
      <label for="{{'file-size-' + i}}" class="form-label">
        <span class="file-size-label">Size</span>
        <span class="file-size-value">{{ file.get('Size').value | fileSize: true }}</span>
        <input [attr.id]="'file-size-' + i" type="hidden" class="form-control" formControlName="Size" placeholder="File Size">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-outline only-icon btn-round" (click)="removeFile(i)">
        <clr-icon shape="times"></clr-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```